# How to inject script into url without slash in Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here is my extension configuration.

```
"content_scripts" : [{

    "all_frames": false,

    "js": ["script.js"],

    "matches": ["XXX.org"]
}],
```

I got error when loading extension.

But it works.

```
"matches": ["XXX.org/*"]
```

I need to inject script into root link not sub link.

Thank

Comment: I meant. "https://www.my.site.com/*" is working. But "https://www.my.site.com" is getting failed.

Answer (score 1):

`http://example.com` is not a final URL; it's simply a shortcut for `http://example.com/` - it will be rewritten by the browser, even if it's not shown in the address bar. After all, you still need a path for a `GET` request!

Chrome documentation clearly states that [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) *must* include a path (and a scheme). If you only want the site's root, then match only against that:

```
"matches": ["http://example.com/"]
```